React native resource file access from assets of each platform for android and ios
In react native, I'm using the assets folder of android which is located at android/app/src/main/assets for access resource files.
How can I access resources files in iOS?
I'm using the .html file to render in webview.
I got the solution for android, but I need the solution for the iOS platform.
I would appreciate your help!

you should create an assets folder inside src folder and store your files there. And try this solution.

To access resource files in iOS, include resource files in the Xcode project and reference it.
First install: npm install react-native-webview
import React from 'react';
import {WebView} from 'react-native-webview';
import {Playtfom} from 'react-native';
import {NativeModules} from 'react-native';
const MyWebView=()->{
const filePath = Platform.OS==='ios'?'local-page.html':'file:///android_asset/local-page.html';
return(
   <WebView 
   originWhitelist={['*']}
   source={
      Platform.OS==='ios'?require('./local-page.html'):{uri:filePath}
}
/>
)
};

